# How does the quantum landscape of Mersini-Houghton's multiverse theory become physical?

Tags: cosmology, cosmological-inflation, multiverse

In her new book (*Before the Big Bang*), Dr. Laura Mersini-Houghton elegantly describes the "quantum landscape of the multiverse", an abstract quantum field of energies where an inflaton (theoretical particle) may settle into one of $10^{600}$ possible vacua and thereby bang into a classical universe. She demonstrates that our universe (contrary to Roger Penrose's pronouncement) is not unlikely and does not depend on the anthropic principle for its existence. In fact, our universe is highly likely, even ordinary. My question is, where would we find such a quantum landscape? She labels it abstract, yet wholeheartedly believes it to be the one and true parent of our universe and every other. CMB data from WMAP and Planck missions support her theory. Is the landscape a) a quantum field that exists everywhere eternally? b) a place in Hilbert space outside of our universe and every other? c) purely abstract, capable of explaining how an inflaton creates a universe, but otherwise not physical?

Comment: Background: https://inspirehep.net/authors/997726, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.6275.pdf. I think the $10^{600}$ is string theory landscape, blah blah blah, someone can answer better

Comment: She had predicted the existence of a large void, evidently within our observable region, whose existence was later confirmed astronomically.  I (a layperson) had a vague recollection of her having also predicted a sort of central region of a multiverse that was briefly described in work by Martin Bojowald, and there is, in fact, a reference to her work in the bibliography of an arxiv preprint of a work by Bojowald.  That reference was as follows: Mersini-Houghton, Notes on Time’s Enigma, arXiv:0909.2330   .

Comment: Here's the Arxiv preprint of the paper that Bojowald had quoted:  https://arxiv.org/abs/0909.2330.  It may be a little clearer than her pop-sci book, which is rather emotional, as it dealt with her escape from an authoritarian regime.

Comment: Skipping to the "Discussion" end of her preprint didn't clarify things enough for me to be able to field an answer yet.  Plus, being a Yank, I've got my own RE-emergent authoritarian regime to sweat...!

Comment: Seriously, did Mersini-Houghton use the term "abstract"?  (I read her pop-sci book, & don't recall noticing that generally unphysical term.)